# Matrix derivative of block-diagonal matrix of covariance matrices, with respect to matrix square root

Tags: matrix-calculus

My matrix calculus is entirely self-taught (and the only formal univariate calculus that I had was in high school), so I'm proud to have made it as far as I have.  But I am stumped.  Here is the problem:
$$
y = \mathbf{a^T \Psi b}\\
\mathbf{\Psi} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbf{B^TB} \\
& \mathbf{B^TB}\\
&& \mathbf{B^TB}\\
\end{array} \right]
$$
What is 
$
\partial y/\partial \mathbf{B}???
$

Assume $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are $P \times 1$ such that $y$ is a scalar.  $\mathbf{B}$ is $m\times m$.

Some context: I want to find the gradients for the elements of $\mathbf{B}$, rather than the actual covariance matrices that $\mathbf{B}$ comprises, because this result will be used in an unconstrained optimizer, and I want all real values to be admissible.

I know that a general $\partial y/\partial x$ where $y = \mathbf{X^TX}$ is equal to $2\mathbf{X^T}\partial{\mathbf{X}}/\partial x$.  If the elements of $\mathbf{X}$ are just constants, then $\partial{\mathbf{X}}/\partial x$ is just $\mathbf{X}$ with a one somewhere, corresponding to the position of $x$ for whom the derivative is being taken.

Does this imply that the answer is simply
$$
\partial y/\partial\mathbf{B}  = \mathbf{a}^T\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbf{2B^TI} \\
& \mathbf{2B^TI}\\
&& \mathbf{2B^TI}\\
\end{array} \right]\mathbf{b}
$$
Seems too easy...

Answer (score 1):

The gradient that you seek is
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial B} = \sum_k BG_k\,{\rm tr}(F_k)$$
where the matrices $(F_k,G_k)$ come from the decomposition
$$(ab^T+ba^T) = \sum_k F_k\otimes G_k$$
and the matrices $F_k$ are shaped like $I_3$, and $G_k$ are like $B^TB$.

Here's how the gradient was derived.

First let's denote the trace/Frobenius product with a colon, i.e. $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Write the objective function using the Frobenius product and find its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 y &= ab^T:(I_3\otimes B^TB) \cr
\cr
dy
 &= ab^T:(I_3\otimes dB^T\,B+I_3\otimes B^T\,dB) \cr
 &= ab^T:(I_3\otimes dB^T\,B)+ab^T:(I_3\otimes B^T\,dB) \cr
 &= ba^T:(I_3\otimes B^T\,dB)+ab^T:(I_3\otimes B^T\,dB) \cr
 &= (ab^T+ba^T):(I_3\otimes B^T\,dB) \cr
 &= \Big(\sum_k F_k\otimes G_k\Big):(I_3\otimes B^T\,dB) \cr
 &= \Big(\sum_k (F_k:I_3)\,(G_k:B^T\,dB)\Big) \cr
 &= \sum_k {\rm tr}(F_k)\,BG_k :dB \cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial B} &= \sum_k {\rm tr}(F_k)\,BG_k \cr
}$$
For more information on the Kronecker decomposition, search for the classic paper by van Loan & Pitsianis, or for Pitsianis' PhD thesis (which contains Matlab code).

#### Update

The Pitsianis decomposition can be avoided by using the vec operation.

Let
$$\eqalign{
&a = {\rm vec}({\cal A}) \quad&\implies\quad &{\cal A} = {\rm unvec}(a) \\
&b = {\rm vec}({\cal B}) \quad&\implies\quad &{\cal B} = {\rm unvec}(b) \\
}$$
and write the objective function as
$$\eqalign{
y &= a:(I_3\otimes B^TB)b \\
  &= a:{\rm vec}(B^TB\;{\cal B}\;I_3) \\
  &= {\cal A}:B^TB\;{\cal B} \\
  &= {\cal A}{\cal B}^T : B^TB \\
}$$
Finally, calculate the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dy &= {\cal A}{\cal B}^T : (B^TdB + dB^TB) \\
   &= ({\cal A}{\cal B}^T+{\cal B}{\cal A}^T) : B^TdB \\
   &= B\,({\cal A}{\cal B}^T+{\cal B}{\cal A}^T) : dB \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial B}
   &= B\,({\cal A}{\cal B}^T+{\cal B}{\cal A}^T) \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I think I follow your derivation -- you basically just apply the product rule and then some trace rules and then that Kronecker decomposition.  But I've got a few questions: (1) what is $k$?  (2) How exactly does one compute $G$ and $F$ from $a$ and $b$?  (3) Does the answer get simpler if $a = b$?  (4) Does that paper tell me the answers to those things? (5) Are you aware of lecture notes somewhere that are more accessible than that paper?

Comment: @generic_user If you don't need the full gradient, and just want to know how $y$ changes for a corresponding change in $B$, then you can skip the decomposition and say $$dy=(ab^T+ba^T):(I\otimes B^T\,dB)$$ Otherwise: (1) $k$ is a summation index since the Kronecker decomposition can have more than 1 term, (2) see Pitsianis' thesis for the details of the computation, (3) the only difference would be $(ab^T+ba^T)=2aa^T$, (4) yes, and (5) the papers are quite good and better than any lecture notes.

Comment: Irrespective of whether that paper and thesis are "good,", they certainly aren't accessible to me.  And are they relevant?  Pitsianis seems to be focused on finding two kronecker factors to approximate a given matrix.  Perhaps there is some connection between my problem and his that I am failing to grok.